# Threejs cover single image on each box face without repeat

Tags: three.js

Suppose i have one gltf model like given here: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/box-d919737a5a5b464f809d12f7e1fad78f. and cover image like given below: [image: cover image for box]

I have to cover this image on full box not each layer separately.
Below is my code to apply texture on object.

```
var loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/gltf/box/' );
            loader.load( 'scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                  var model = gltf.scene;
                  model.traverse ( ( o ) => {
                    if ( o.isMesh ) {
                      o.material.map = texture;
                    }
                  } );
                scene.add( model );
                render();

            } );
```

Results of code is like given in below image but i have to wrap single image in continues manner to all side.
[image]
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: And how the box has to look like? Could you provide an explanatory picture with desired result?

Comment: @prisoner849 i am sorry but i am not that much good in photoshop but imagine some part of cover on left part then front will continue from where left over and also image cover full box without repeat. something like given in link here: https://goodmockups.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Free-Shoe-Box-Packaging-Mockup-PSD-Set-2.jpg

Comment: @prisoner849 please find similar example here: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/little-package-box-juice-fe9234b2763a4db79320f25cbce9f5a5

Comment: you can change uv coordinates on each side.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default texture-mapping behavior of a standard Three.js cube. If you need to modify the way the texture is mapped, then you'll have to perform your own [UV Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) and import the geometry into Three.js so they follow the pattern that you desire. For example, if you want to create a 6-sided die, you'll have to edit your UVs so they follow this pattern:

[image]

I recommend [you use Blender](https://www.blender.org/) to do this because it's free, easy, and it has a built-in GLTF exporter that you can use with Three.js.

Comment: Hi @Marquizzo thanks for you help, i have dynamic design i mean from canvas.toDataURL value wants to apply as texture on object in that case i can use blender exporter gltf or create with json is better! I am new for both the case. also any further guiding article help if you can give me.